# Choose what apps mute all other sounds on VOIP call in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, sip, voip

**Is it possible for Windows 10 to choose what apps should mute all other sounds when I am on a VOIP call?**

I know that Windows does it for Skype and games, but I use mostly SIP protocol programs like Zoiper or Jitsy. When using these, and when I make / receive a call, other sounds are never muted. I am usually listening to music simultaneously from a browser, and its annoying to have to manually lower the volume everytime I have to VOIP. Its even harder because I have to switch virtual desktops also to do it, because I keep work v.desktop away from the rest.

I've searched all over the windows control panel, and also googled around but couldn't find any options for this. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. The app have to make some system call so the OS will recognize it as a VoIP app and reduce the volume for all other apps.
However I don't know on which API call this is relied on. 
I hope that somebody will answer this.